# How to find back from generating function $\sum(Q(x)*z^m/m!)$ to $Q(x)$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

How to find back from generating function $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(Q(x)\frac{z^m}{m!})$ to $Q$?

In other words, find $Q$ from $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(Q(x)\frac{z^m}{m!})$.

finally is generating function depends on $x$ and $z$

**Update**
The reason for this backward action, is forward action from dsolve differential equation
solved as special function such as kummer, even convert to ratpoly also can not be success

for example

$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(Q(x)\frac{z^m}{m!})$ = 2/(Pi*(exp(x/z)+exp(-x/z)))

how subs(z=0, diff(f, z$k)) when z is denominator?
how many times should we diff ?

Please don't down vote, really need this

Comment: Usually $Q$ depends upon $m$, but you haven't indicated that.

Comment: You need to recover a sequence from its generating function.

Comment: So, you're asking how to find the coefficients of a Taylor series of a function?

Comment: When you realize you've asked a poor question, the thing to do is to make your question better, rather than plead that people overlook the fact it's poor....

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, i edit it in terms of x and z now

Comment: If $Q$ is just a function of $x$, you can distribute it out as in did's answer from before.

Comment: If the "variables" $x$ and $z$ are unrelated, you can just treat $Q(x)$ as constant (which is, in the sense that $dQ/dz=0$ identically) and the problem is absolutely trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $S=\sum\limits_{m=0}^{+\infty}Q\frac{z^m}{m!}$ is such that $S=Q\cdot\mathrm e^z$, one has $Q=S\cdot\mathrm e^{-z}=S\cdot\sum\limits_{m=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^m\frac{z^m}{m!}$.

Comment: not fully understand, is it really S = Q*exp(z)? as Q is not a constant

Comment: @M-Askman: Ross has already asked you if Q is dependent on m.  Without answering him, people can only assume what you wrote, and you wrote no dependence.  That means you can simply use the distributive property, and get did's answer.

Comment: sorry, if Q is constant, did is correct, usually classic generating function's Q is in terms of x

Answer (score 1):

If
$$
S(z)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty Q_m\frac{z^m}{m!}
$$
(note that the coefficient $Q_m$ does depend on $m$) then, rather obviously,
$$
Q_k=\frac{d^kS}{dz^k}(0)
$$
for all $k\geq0$.

Comment: how many times should we diff S?

Comment: @M-Askman $k$-times to obtain the $k$-th coefficient.

Comment: it sounds k-th coefficient of taylor series, not well understand how to do after get kth coefficient, the goal for Q is z-transform Q

Comment: Well, if the coefficient depends on $x$ different from $z$ the procedure remains the same: if there is a dependance from $m$ you get it differentiating as I said, if not the problem it is even more trivial and see did's answer.